# Calculate MySQL's WEEK Function with mode argument In Oracle

Tags: mysql, oracle, week-number

I would like to know is there a way to calculate Mysql's week function in Oracle. I know that we can get week number by using `to_char([date],IW')` which considers Monday as first date of week.

I know that MySQL has 7 modes with week function, can I do this in oracle?

If not possible then is there a way to get MySQL's `week([date],0)` function  alternative in Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a custom function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION week_zero( i_date IN DATE ) RETURN NUMBER
IS
BEGIN
  RETURN FLOOR( ( i_date - NEXT_DAY( TRUNC( i_date, 'YY' ) - INTERVAL '1' DAY, 'SUNDAY' ) ) / 7 ) + 1;
END;
/
```

*Oracle db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8e416e9110f7d6cf1853649035d344fd)*

*Equivalent MySQL db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b66256d63debc91e248937c19143de34)*